# Selecting columns in numpy based on a Boolean vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays `a`, `b` with dimensions `m` by `n`. I have a Boolean vector `b` of length `n` and I want to produce a new array `c`, which selects the `n` columns from `a`, `b`, so that if `b[i]` is true, I take the column from `b` otherwise from `a`.

How do I do this in the most efficient way possible?
I've looked at `select`, `where` and `choose`.

Comment: Could you provide some sample (dummy) data and your expected output? I know you have explained it quite clearly but it does help others (me actually) better understand your question in a visual sense

Comment: please forget what I said, others are just so good at understanding and have already come with solutions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, let's set up some example code:

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 5, 3
a = np.zeros((m, n))
b = np.ones((m, n))

boolvec = np.random.randint(0, 2, m).astype(bool)
```

Just to show what this data might look like:

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [4]: boolvec
Out[4]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

In this case, it's most efficient to use `np.where` for this.  However, we need `boolvec` to be of a shape that can broadcast to the same shape as `a` and `b`.  Therefore, we can make it a column vector by slicing with `np.newaxis` or `None` (they're the same):

```
In [5]: boolvec[:,None]
Out[5]: 
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

And then we can make the final result using `np.where`:

```
In [6]: c = np.where(boolvec[:, None], a, b)

In [7]: c
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, `where` is faster than `choose`.  I did not need to use `np.newaxis` as broadcasting seemed to work?

Comment: @NeilG - It depends on whether `boolvec` is `m`-length or `n`-length. `np.where` assumes slightly different things than "normal" indexing would.  You can index with `boolvec` if it's `m`-length, but `np.where` expects it to broadcast, which applies along the last axis. Therefore, if `boolvec` is `m`-length, you'll need to slice with `np.newaxis`, and if it's `n`-length, you won't (or, rather, you can, but you'd do `boolvec[None, :]`).

Comment: Also, I just realized I misread your original question.  You were asking about an `n`-length vector, in which case `np.where` works as-is.

Comment: Right, thanks.  In general, I prefer writing `np.newaxis` for readability.  :)

Comment: Absolutely!  It's quite arguably better! (I was just lazy)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `np.choose` for this.

For example `a` and `b` arrays:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4) + 100
>>> a_and_b = np.array([a, b])
```

To use `np.choose`, we want a 3D array with both arrays; `a_and_b` looks like this:

```
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3],
        [  4,   5,   6,   7],
        [  8,   9,  10,  11]],

       [[100, 101, 102, 103],
        [104, 105, 106, 107],
        [108, 109, 110, 111]]])
```

Now let the Boolean array be `bl = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])`. Then:

```
>>> np.choose(bl, a_and_b)
array([[  0, 101, 102,   3],
       [  4, 105, 106,   7],
       [  8, 109, 110,  11]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Timings for (5000,3000) arrays are:

```
In [107]: timeit np.where(boolvec[:,None],b,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 993 ms per loop

In [108]: timeit np.choose(boolvec[:,None],[a,b])
1 loops, best of 3: 929 ms per loop

In [109]: timeit c=a[:];c[boolvec,:]=b[boolvec,:]
1 loops, best of 3: 786 ms per loop
```

`where` and `choose` are essentially the same; boolean indexing slightly faster.  `select` uses `choose`, so I didn't time it.

---

My timings for column sampling are similar, except this time the indexing is slower:

```
In [119]: timeit np.where(cols,b,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 878 ms per loop

In [120]: timeit np.choose(cols,[a,b])
1 loops, best of 3: 915 ms per loop

In [121]: timeit c=a[:];c[:,cols]=b[:,cols]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop
```

Correction, for the indexing I should be using `a.copy()`.

```
In [32]: timeit c=a.copy();c[boolvec,:]=b[boolvec,:]
1 loops, best of 3: 783 ms per loop
In [33]: timeit c=a.copy();c[:,cols]=b[:,cols]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.44 s per loop
```

I get the same timings for Python2.7 and 3, numpy 1.8.2 and 1.9.0 dev

Comment: On my computer choose was twice as slow.  Not sure why.